# Get rid of absolut links / redirects

Tags: 6, theming, navigation

I just got a project from a friend:
D6, 6.34, 3 languages.
Theme: Sharp Sales (via Fusion via Topnotch)
So quite an ancient project and I first installed a local copy, but I can't login - it keeps on forwarding me to the live server.
I deleted the rewrites in .htacces, deleted cache, watchdog, access_log tables and I searched for redirects in the database, but it seems to come from the theme somehow:

```
INSERT INTO `cache` VALUES ('theme_registry:tnt_sharpsales_6',
...
:\"skinr_preprocess\";}}s:23:\"link_formatter_absolute\";a:8:{s:9:\"arguments\";a:1:{s:7:\"element\";N;}s:4:\"file\";s:14:\"link.theme.inc\";s:4:\"type\";s:6:\"module\";s:10:\"theme path\";s:22
```

and I found sth in the template.php as well:

```
* @param $options
 *   An associative array that contains the following other arrays and values
 *     @param $attributes
 *       An associative array of HTML attributes to apply to the anchor tag.
 *     @param $query
 *       A query string to append to the link.
 *     @param $fragment
 *       A fragment identifier (named anchor) to append to the link.
 *     @param $absolute
 *       Whether to force the output to be an absolute link (beginning with     http:).
 *       Useful for links that will be displayed outside the site, such as     in an RSS
 *       feed.
 *     @param $html
 *       Whether the title is HTML or not (plain text)
 * @return
 *   an HTML string containing a link to the given path.
 */
function tnt_sharpsales_6_themesettings_link($prefix, $suffix, $text,         $path, $options) {
  return $prefix . (($text) ? l($text, $path, $options) : '') . $suffix;
}
```

So I installed a fresh D6 and copied the theme over, but I can't find a setting there for absolut links.
Anybody any idea how I could get rid of the absolut links?

Comment: is base_url set in settings.php?

Comment: Just tried it on and off - no changes so far.  

I managed to use drush to switch to garland - at least I can access individual pages now but all the links are still pointing to the live server.

Comment: $base_url is not something that you switch on and off but the config var that tells Drupal the URL of your site. If it is misconfigured you can get weird behaviours like those you describe.

Comment: Yes, I mean - I tried it with and without $base_url set - but the outcome was always the same, no effect there.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out:
Issue derived from the language negotiation settings.
Under: admin/settings/language/configure Domain name only was configured and I switched it in the database (manually updated the variables table):

```
UPDATE `dinilu6`.`variable` SET `value` = 's:1:"2";' WHERE `variable`.`name` = 'language_negotiation';
```

Afterwards I needed to clear the cach with **drush cc** and then it finally worked.